# authetification with Pinterest App

Tags: oauth-2.0, pinterest

I created an App in Pinterest and I'm trying to auth using Oauth2. When I submit the form to give Authorization to the App with email and password I have a pop-up :

"Le paramètre consumer_id est obligatoire"

I dont understand the problem and what is this "consumer_id" ??

Thx for help.

Comment: I believe "Le paramètre consumer_id est obligatoire" means "The parameter consumed_id is required".  Are you providing a consumer_id parameter?

Comment: I don't know what this parameter means ? Where can I find it ?

Comment: Please show your code. There is no such "consumer_id" in the pinterest API.